# Mage::getModel but from another database don't work

Tags: database, pdo, model, magento-1.9, external

I've managed to create a module that can connect to a second database next that one from the shop. It started an setup script to create the new table and I inserted one test data.
So far so good.

Now I want to get that data inside an observer.
I can get the model and the collection. Bbut when I count that collection it returns null. When I try getSelectSql(true) on that model that query looks like:

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `custom_table` AS `main_table`
```

Running that query in the database returns my added test data.

app/etc/local.xml

```
<config>
  <global>
    <resources>
      <external_db>
        <connection>
          <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
          <username><![CDATA[db_user]]></username>
          <password><![CDATA[db_pass]]></password>
          <dbname><![CDATA[external_db]]></dbname>
          <active>1</active>
        </connection>
```

Observer

```
public function validateRequest(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    try {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('custom_module/custom_table')->getCollection();
        $items = $collection->getItems();
```

That returns me the following exception:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'shop.custom_table' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `custom_table` AS `main_table`

It looks like magento isn't able to choose the correct connection.
But I can't find the way to change that in a magento way.

The only way it works is:

```
$resource   = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$conn       = $resource->getConnection('externaldb_read');
$results    = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM custom_table');
```

I would like to do it without creating raw queries.

Answer (score 1):

use setConnection() method before you load your collection. The Argument should be a valid core/resource object with your database selected.

Comment: I was running in exact same issue. I had defined the 2nd database connection as a resource in config.xml but the module's collection model kept running queries on default (core) database. Adding following code fixed my issue. `$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource'); $conn     = $resource->getConnection('mymodule_read'); $collection->setConnection($conn);` where `mymodule_read` is defined to `<use>` my custom database resource. Thanks a bunch.